# Why don't newtypes use the traits from the inner type?

Tags: rust, newtype

In rust 1.0.0-nightly, this code works fine:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 10f64;
    let y = 20f64;
    let z = x + y;
    println!("z = {}", z);
}
```

But if I try to use a newtype (according to the [rust book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/compound-data-types.html#tuple-structs-and-newtypes)):

```
struct Metres(f64);

fn main() {
    let x = Metres(10f64);
    let y = Metres(20f64);
    let z = x + y;
    println!("z = {}", z);
}
```

I get this compiler error:

```
test.rs:6:13: 6:18 error: binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `Metres`
test.rs:6     let z = x + y;
                      ^~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Since `Metres` is basically a `f64`, why can't the compiler use the same `+` operator, and create a new `Metres` object for `z`?

How can I use newtypes if I can't do simple things like adding and such? How are they "very useful" (as the book calls them)?

*(There is an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831573/automatically-implement-traits-of-enclosed-type-for-rust-newtypes-tuple-struc) about this, but rust changes a lot, hence I'm reasking)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason newtypes work this way is generally because you *want* to avoid the traits defined on the underlying type. For example, you could have `Metres` and `Feet` which both wrap `f64` but define addition of `Metres` and `Feet` to do unit conversion, which plain `f64` addition doesn't give you.

Of course, sometimes you do want the underlying trait implementation. Currently, you'd have to write a wrapper implementation yourself, but there is an RFC for the ability to generate these automatically: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/479

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. It's a shame there's no shorter way to derive things.

Comment: As of Mar. 28, 2016, the crate `derive_more` will do this for many common traits like `Add`, `Sub`, `MulAssign`, etc.  https://crates.io/crates/derive_more

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by Scott Olson, it is actually voluntary that newtypes do not "degenerate" in their only attribute. They are here to introduce a new type, after all.

If all you want is a synonym, which is slightly different, then you can use a type alias instead:

```
type Metres = f64;
```

However, you then lose the benefits of a new type:

```
type Grams = f64;

fn main() {
    let m = 10 as Metres;
    let g = 5 as Grams;
    println!("{}", m + g); // prints 15, see http://is.gd/IdYOEg
}
```