# Hide private type in exported signature

Tags: types, rust, private, encapsulation, public

In this example, `NoGood` is pub, and `AtomWord` is private.

I'd like to export an instance of `IntoIterator`, but I can't because this huge type definition for `IntoIter` includes a reference to `AtomWord`.

I realize I could create an `Iterator` wrapper that just passes calls through to the underlying iterator, but that's a lot of boilerplate. I can't think of any way to make the wrapper class generic (without defeating the purpose, which is to hide the `AtomWord` type).

```
impl <'a> IntoIterator for &'a NoGood {
    type Item = Literal;
    type IntoIter = FilterMap<slice::Iter<'a, AtomWord>, fn(&AtomWord) -> Option<Literal>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        (&self.lits).into_iter().filter_map(as_opt_lit)
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the wrapper class solution would be pretty good if Rust had something like GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving.  Does it?

Comment: Since it's only one trait with one method that needs to be implemented here, the wrapper solution seems accepted (though not ideal, obviously).

Comment: alternatively box the iterator: `type IntoIter = Box<Iterator<Item=Literal>>`

Comment: @dspyz sadly, it doesn't have that functionality (yet?). I'd love something to help with delegation in general and wrapper structs in particular though.

Comment: This question [talks a bit more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24835982/155423) about `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot hide a private type in a public method. It's public, which means that people need to see it.

As [delnan mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895960/hide-private-type-in-exported-signature#comment51708542_31895960), the wrapper struct is common for iterators. It also happens to have zero runtime cost:

```
struct Iter<'a>(FilterMap<slice::Iter<'a, AtomWord>, fn(&AtomWord) -> Option<Literal>>);

impl<'a> Iterator for Iter<'a> {
    type Item = Literal;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Literal> {
        self.0.next()
    }
}

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a NoGood {
    type Item = Literal;
    type IntoIter = Iter;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        Iter((&self.lits).into_iter().filter_map(as_opt_lit))
    }
}
```

And as [ker mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31895960/hide-private-type-in-exported-signature#comment51708872_31895960), you can box it. This saves programmer typing time, but at the expense of runtime memory allocation:

```
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a NoGood {
    type Item = Literal;
    type IntoIter = Box<Iterator<Item = Literal>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        Box::new((&self.lits).into_iter().filter_map(as_opt_lit))
    }
}
```

Note that I haven't tried compiling any of these because you didn't provide an [MCVE](/help/mcve) and thus your code doesn't compile anyway.

Comment: Iterator has tons of methods.  For optimal performance, shouldn't I have implementations of all of them?  At least I should have size_hint, shouldn't I?

Comment: @dspyz good question! [Right now](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24214), there aren't many types in the standard library that effectively implement the iterator methods themselves. However, I think you are right that for better performance, you would forward all those methods to the inner field. I think this is what your `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` would help with...