# Automatically derive Add, Mul, Ord, etc. for a numeric type

Tags: rust, deriving, newtype

What's the simplest way to create a custom type that behaves like a number?

I want type-checking that prevents mixing different units in my program, but I still want to be able to easily perform calculations on the type without casting back and forth (similar case to custom `Centimeters` and `Inches` types).

If I create:

```
struct Centimeters(f64);
```

then I have to implement `Add`, `Mul`, `Ord` and lots of other traits manually. That's a lot of boilerplate, and copy&pasting of this code creates a  risk of breaking basic arithmetic in the program :)

Unfortunately `#[derive(Add, Sub, …)]` doesn't seem to be supported. Is there another standard trait/type/crate that could achieve similar effect?

Comment: You should try my crate that adds exactly this functionality for lots of traits: https://github.com/JelteF/derive_more

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Units of Measurement

You should have a look at https://crates.io/crates/measurements. That crate contains definitions for many units of measurement like centimeters, feet, etc.

## Implementing traits for your newtypes

There are now some crates that make it really easy to implement `Add`, `Mul`, etc. for your newtypes.

### [derive_more](https://github.com/JelteF/derive_more)

```
// This needs rust in the 2018 edition
extern crate derive_more;
use derive_more::{Add, Mul};

#[derive(Add, Mul)]
struct Centimeters(i32);
```

### [newtype_derive](https://crates.io/crates/newtype_derive)

```
custom_derive! {
  #[derive(NewtypeAdd, NewtypeMul)]
  pub struct Centimeters(i32);
}
```

### Traits with your own macro

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24835982/783912) answer has a nice macro to help you implement traits for your newtypes.

Comment: It looks like all solutions use macros, so I've suggested adding this to the language: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/deriving-for-tuple-structs/2477

Comment: With rust 1.15 you can now use my crate to do this: https://github.com/JelteF/derive_more