# Is there a simple way to implement `Ord` trait for a key value pair whose order is only determined by its key?

Tags: rust

I want to implement a `KeyValuePair<K, V>` data structure that implements `Ord` if `K` implements `Ord`. Currently, this is my implementation:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

struct KeyValuePair<K, V> {
    key: K,
    value: V,
}

impl<K: PartialEq, V> PartialEq for KeyValuePair<K, V> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.key.eq(&other.key)
    }
}

impl<K: Eq, V> Eq for KeyValuePair<K, V> {}

impl<K: PartialOrd, V> PartialOrd for KeyValuePair<K, V> {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        self.key.partial_cmp(&other.key)
    }
}

impl<K: Ord, V> Ord for KeyValuePair<K, V> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.key.cmp(&other.key)
    }
}
```

Other than `Ord`, I also have to implement `PartialEq`, `Eq` and `PartialOrd`, which is a bit too much. I don’t want to use `#[derive]` because that will compare `value` as well.

So is there any way I can simplify my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a macro that implements Ord by delegating to a struct member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664392/is-it-possible-to-create-a-macro-that-implements-ord-by-delegating-to-a-struct-m)

Comment: what do you want simplify ? There is 3 lines of code

Comment: you can do `Some(self.cmp(other))` in `PartialOrd`

Comment: @Stargateur I can’t use `Some(self.cmp(other))` in `PartialOrd` because I only constrain `K` to be `PartialOrd`, not `Ord`, and `PartialOrd` doesn’t have `cmp`.

Comment: @Stargateur The linked solution uses macros, which doesn’t reduce the code size because it still do 4 trait implementations in the macro definition.

Comment: Yes, that the point, there is nothing to simplify.