# Is there a way to access inner struct fields of a tuple struct without writing the `.0`?

Tags: rust

After reading the chapter about the tuple structure and transparent layout. In case of struct definitions like this:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub(crate) struct InnerStruct {
    pub a: u32,
    pub b: u32,
    pub c: u32,
}

#[repr(transparent)]
pub OuterStruct(pub(crate) InnerStruct);
```

Normally we get access to inner struct's fields as following:

```rust
let outer = OuterStruct(...);
outer.0.a
outer.0.b
```

Is there any way to access these fields directly, like `outer.a` or `outer.b` without writing the `.0`?

Comment: *reading the chapter* — **which** chapter? Link to it please.

Comment: See also [Automatically implement traits of enclosed type for Rust newtypes (tuple structs with one field)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24831573/155423); [Is it considered a bad practice to implement Deref for newtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45086595/155423)