# In Rust is there a way to create a new different type from a primitive that works completly same as it?

Tags: rust

For example if I define type aliases as follows

```rust
pub type UserID = usize;
pub type UserScore = f32;

pub type ItemID = usize:
pub type ItemScore = f32;
```

I cannot prevent passing an `ItemID` variable to a function that accepts a `UserID` argument.

Next if I use tuple struct

```rust
pub struct UserScore(f32);
pub struct ItemScore(f32);
```

This time I can prevent passing an `ItemScore` variable to a function which accepts a `UserScore` argument. However I cannot for example directly add two `UserScore` variables. I have to implement `Add` trait in this case.

Is there a way to create a Primitive like struct that inherits all of the properties of the base type but cannot be mixed with other types?

Comment: Please don't tag a language just because you want to do something that you think is easy in that language. Tags are for describing the *question*, and Python experts don't have a special advantage in knowing how to solve this problem. Anyway, it's almost always better to describe a feature in terms of *concretely what needs to happen*, instead of talking about some other language. Porting code from one programming language to another is not mechanical or simple; if it were, one of the two languages would not exist.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831573/automatically-implement-traits-of-enclosed-type-for-rust-newtypes-tuple-structs